# How to verify if the token expired

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, async-await, sequelize.js

I want to verify if the token expired and then send a status and a message

```
 async function verify () {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: req.body.token,
    audience: CLIENT_ID
  })
  const payload = ticket.getPayload()
  let email = payload['email']
  return User
    .findOne({
      where: { email: email }
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return next(boom.notFound('User not found'))
      }
      let token = jwt.sign({user}, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
      })
      user.token = token
      return res.status(200).send(user)
    })
}
verify().catch(console.error)}
```

I've been traying with client.isTokenExpiring() but doesn't catch the error

Comment: What type of token is this? I think this question needs more context to be answered. This function is signing a `jwt`, but then you also want to verify the above `idToken`? Can you provide more details?

Comment: I receive a google token and i verify that token, then I extract the email from the google token and look for the email in my data base, if excist I generate a token with the user and I return the model user with the token genereted.

But now what I want to do is: catch if the google token has exprided and if so, do something like this: `res.status(401).json({'err': 'Token has expired'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough client side answer to your question. I recall in a previous post you linked to here that you were working on Google Web Login so I've answered from client perspective .

I don't have the same code as you for this problem, but in general this is what I did:

Extract the expiration date from the token. Check if the current time is later than or equal to the expiration on the token, then call the `reloadAuthReponse` method on the auth instance you are using. This will update your token. In fact, I do this every time the computer wakes from sleep.

This snippet includes helper functions from moment.js to compare times, but the general idea follows:

```
if(now.isSame(exp) || now.isAfter(exp)) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().reloadAuthResponse().then(function() {
        // do something with the new token
    });
}
```